Building an Virtual Camera that Receives frames with RTP
I litle interduction to my Project so i have an virtual camera that i build with Directshow, Works how t supposed to work, then i installed an external library uvgRTP and made the code so i receive the frames in a separate thread works fine . i made an queue that puts those frames in a queue and the fillbuffer then proccess those frames. I have an image , infact i have an actualy good video for about 6 seconds and then i get extrem lagg , the RTP frames im receiving are not the problem cus those are tested. im not sure whats the issue im getting a sense that fillbuffer cant quiet handle it after 6 seconds maybe he isnt fast enough but that shouldnt be a problem , does anybody have any experience with Directshow filter virtual cameras that can help me out.
so here are my code for the RTP receiving and sending it to a queue:
void CVCamStream::rtpThreadProc(CVCamStream* obj) {
    constexpr uint16_t LOCAL_PORT = 12480;
    constexpr char LOCAL_ADDRESS[] = "::";
    uvgrtp::context ctx;
    uvgrtp::session* sess = ctx.create_session(LOCAL_ADDRESS);
    int flags = RCE_RECEIVE_ONLY;
    uvgrtp::media_stream* receiver = sess->create_stream(LOCAL_PORT, RTP_FORMAT_H264, flags);

    if (receiver) {
        while (!obj->m_quit_thread) {
            uvgrtp::frame::rtp_frame* frame = receiver->pull_frame();
            if (frame) {
                std::vector<uint8_t> newFrame(frame->payload, frame->payload + frame->payload_len);
                obj->frameBuffer_.Push(newFrame);
                uvgrtp::frame::dealloc_frame(frame);
            }
        }
    }
    if (sess) {
        ctx.destroy_session(sess);
    }
}

lets explain it a litle bit so this is a thread that works as separate program in my project. i got the code from the uvgRTP library examples , i it creates a session ipv6 and then we are abble to pullframes that are beeing send using the
uvgrtp::frame::rtp_frame* frame = receiver->pull_frame() method so it pullsframe if we get a frame it makes a vector out of those frames that
i use as an image to display it and those frame use the function push so if we receive frames it pushes those frames in my class Framebuffer
class FrameBuffer {
public:
    // Push a new frame onto the queue
    void Push(const std::vector<uint8_t>& frame) {
        // Locks the queue with a mutex to prevent concurrent access issues
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
        // Adds the new frame to the end of the queue
        queue_.push(frame);
        condVar_.notify_one(); // Notify one waiting thread

        // Debugging: Logs the addition of a new frame and the current queue size
        std::wstringstream wss;
        wss << L"Pushed a frame. Queue size: " << queue_.size() << L"\n";
        OutputDebugString(wss.str().c_str());
    }

    // Pop a frame from the queue
    bool Pop(std::vector<uint8_t>& frame) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
        while (queue_.empty()) {
            condVar_.wait(lock); // Wait until there's a frame
            // Optional: Return false or break if shutting down
        }

        // Once there are at least 100 frames, proceed to pop a frame
        frame = std::move(queue_.front());
        queue_.pop();

        return true;
    }

this is the framebuffer class if we just pay a litle attention it should pop the first frame and add others in queue . i have debug it im receiving frames like this
in the debug it looks like this
"Pushed a frame. Queue size:10
"Pushed a frame. Queue size:5
"Pushed a frame. Queue size:9
"Pushed a frame. Queue size:12
so it isnt constant the queue size ideal would be queue size 1 cus the fillbuffer doesnt proccess it fast enough
uvgrtp::frame::rtp_frame* frame = receiver->pull_frame();
then we have the fillbuffer code :
HRESULT CVCamStream::FillBuffer(IMediaSample* pms) {
    std::vector<uint8_t> frameData;
    frameBuffer_.Pop(frameData);
    long bufferSize = pms->GetSize();
    if (bufferSize < frameData.size()) {
        return E_FAIL;
    }
    BYTE* pData = nullptr;
    pms->GetPointer(&pData);
    memcpy(pData, frameData.data(), frameData.size());
    pms->SetActualDataLength(frameData.size());
    return NOERROR;
}

we have here the fillbuffer this one is a like now a separate thread so we have 2 threads trying to work togheter , the receiving frames using  RTP and the processing those frames that the fillbuffer does so looking at the frame queue size it is geting lower and biger but doesnt exeed more then 20frames in queue cus that much can handle the fillbuffer. so the fillbuffer receives those frames from the queue and process it
too add this is the format i use to get my h264 decoder , so this is a example of h264 frames without starter code
HRESULT CVCamStream::GetMediaType(CMediaType* pMediaType)
{
   
    pMediaType->InitMediaType();
    pMediaType->SetType(&MEDIATYPE_Video);
    pMediaType->SetSubtype(&MEDIASUBTYPE_AVC1);
    pMediaType->SetFormatType(&FORMAT_MPEG2_VIDEO);

    pMediaType->bFixedSizeSamples = FALSE;
    pMediaType->bTemporalCompression = TRUE;

    // Our H.264 codec only supports baseline, we can't extract 
    // width and height for other .264 sources. In this case
    // the value will still be 0. Hence just set any value.
    unsigned uiWidth = 1080;
    unsigned uiHeight = 2280;

    MPEG2VIDEOINFO* mpeg2 = (MPEG2VIDEOINFO*)pMediaType->AllocFormatBuffer(sizeof(MPEG2VIDEOINFO) + 80);
    ZeroMemory(mpeg2, sizeof(MPEG2VIDEOINFO) + 80);

    mpeg2->dwProfile = 66;
    mpeg2->dwLevel = 51;
    mpeg2->dwFlags = 4;

   /* byte sps[] = {
            103, 66, 128, 10, 218, 1, 12, 4, 118, 128, 109, 10, 19, 80
    };*/
    byte pps[] = { 104, 206, 6, 242, 1, 2, 3, 4 };

    byte parameters[] = {
        // SPS length and data (unchanged)
        0, 14,
        103, 66, 128, 10, 218, 1, 12, 4, 118, 128, 109, 10, 19, 80,
        // Updated PPS length and new data
        0, 8, // Note the length change here to 8 because of the new PPS size
        104, 206, 6, 242, 1, 2, 3, 4 // New PPS data
    };

    mpeg2->cbSequenceHeader = sizeof(parameters);
    memcpy(mpeg2->dwSequenceHeader, parameters, sizeof(parameters));

    VIDEOINFOHEADER2* pvi2 = &mpeg2->hdr;
    pvi2->bmiHeader.biBitCount = 12;
    pvi2->bmiHeader.biPlanes = 3;
    pvi2->bmiHeader.biWidth = uiWidth;
    pvi2->bmiHeader.biHeight = uiHeight;
    pvi2->bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    pvi2->bmiHeader.biSizeImage = DIBSIZE(pvi2->bmiHeader);
    pvi2->bmiHeader.biCompression = FOURCC("lvca");
    //pvi2->AvgTimePerFrame = m_tFrame;
   // pvi2->AvgTimePerFrame = 100000;
    //pvi2->AvgTimePerFrame = 10000000 / 30;
    //SetRect(&pvi2->rcSource, 0, 0, m_cx, m_cy);
    SetRect(&pvi2->rcSource, 0, 0, uiWidth, uiHeight);
    pvi2->rcTarget = pvi2->rcSource;
    pvi2->dwPictAspectRatioX = uiWidth;
    pvi2->dwPictAspectRatioY = uiHeight;
    //pvi2->dwBitRate = 1500000;


    return NOERROR;

} // GetMediaType


I don't think you're accurately describing the problem you're experiencing, just keep stating that you're not doing anything wrong and going straight to a couple of codes with no explanation whatsoever

Im sorry i wasnt clear is it better now , its my first time posting a quesiton . thank you for the understandment

I think you'd better explain exactly what you mean by "i get extrem lagg". In order to solve the problem, the most important thing is to understand what the problem is and what the symptoms are in order to treat it.

Alright sir , so when i start receiving my frames it is all good untill like i reach 3-6 sec after my video the frames that are beeing proccessed are not acting how they suppose to act. its like frame drops . some frames dont get procesed so i the image is all crappy  like trying to run high end game on a low spec pc .

I have not used uvgRTP. However, RTP is an udp protocol, so the rtp packets you receive may be unordered and there may be packet loss. Of course packet loss is rare when you are using local lan. But unordered packets are still very common. Some rtp libraries will adjust the order for you, some won't. I'm not sure which one uvgRTP is. You can print the value of Sequence number in the received rtp packets to see if it's in order or not

yeah that was a nice idea , but i arleady checked it, doesnt seem to be the problem i thing this guy had an similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999242/rtp-buffer-side-effects?rq=3 . but for me it didnt solve it just by adding the boost library into my code

and in the buffer i dont have any timing declared . because it is a live video i dont think i should have one

I'm not talking about timestamps. Although rtp packets do have a timestamp. I'm talking about the Sequence number, which is an integer that represents the sequence number of the rtp packet, which is generated on the sender's side to ensure that it's incrementally sequential, and which is used by the receiver's side to determine the order of the packets and whether there are any packet losses.

yeah i arleady checked it i printed it out in ,my rtp receive thread and it is indeed an incementaly sequential number it looks like this my outputdebug ceived frame with Received frame with sequence number: 60673
Pushed a frame. Queue size: 1
Received frame with sequence number: 60674
Pushed a frame. Queue size: 1
Received frame with sequence number: 60675
Pushed a frame. Queue size: 1
Received frame with sequence number: 60676
Pushed a frame. Queue size: 1
Received frame with sequence number: 60677
Pushed a frame. Queue size: 1
Received frame with sequence number: 60678

Then the problem may not be from the rtp side. Maybe it has something to do with decoding.

yeah you are maybe right . i need to look into it more deeply, i added in my question the format that chooses for me the decoder, that code is for me a bit strange i found it somewhere in gihub but i thought worked good enough to display me an image
