# How to process RTP data for Microsoft directshow MPEG1 decoder

Tags: directshow, rtp, mpeg, decoder

Starting from [videoprocessing project](http://videoprocessing.sourceforge.net/#rtsp), I'm trying to build a directshow filter that connects to a RTSP server becoming a source filter for the Windows MPEG1  decoder (I can not use other formats or decoders having WinCE as OS target).

My filter declares MediaType

- **MEDIATYPE_Video** type
- **FORMAT_MPEGVideo** subtype
- **MEDIASUBTYPE_MPEG1Payload** formatType

Currently, when I connect my rtspSource filter with the **CLSID_CMpegVideoCodec** decoder, I am rendering a black video.

However, if I replace the windows decoder with **CLSID_LAV_VideoDecoderFilter** provided by the LAVFilters project, the video is correctly rendered.

After reading "[How to process raw UDP packets so that they can be decoded by a decoder filter in a directshow source filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665217/how-to-process-raw-udp-packets-so-that-they-can-be-decoded-by-a-decoder-filter-i)", dealing with the same issue for H264 and MPEG-4, I also read the [RFC2250](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2250.txt) and then I have depacketized the data but the result is the same.

Currently I'm sending to decoder packets starting with  [Video Stream Start Code](http://dvd.sourceforge.net/dvdinfo/mpeghdrs.html)

000001 **00** (**Picture**)

or integral packets starting with

000001 **B3** (**Sequence Header**)

and which contain within them also startCode

000001 **B2** (**User Data**)

000001 **B8** (**Group Of Picture**)

000001 **00** (**Picture**)

000001 **01** (**Slice**)

Still referring to the previous link, which deals with H264 and MPEG-4 cases, speak about "**Process data for decoder**" but I am not clear exactly what is expected by the CLSID_CMpegVideoCodec filter, after agreeing the format type MEDIASUBTYPE_MPEG1Payload.
However, adding at the beginning of each sample the three bytes **000001**  or the 4 bytes **00000100**, the video is rendered with images updated approximately every 2 seconds and losing the intermediate images.

I performed the tests both by setting the IMediaSample with

```
SetTime(NULL, NULL)
```

that setting

```
SetTime(start, start+1)
```

with:

```
start = (rtp_timestamp - rtp_timestamp_first_packet) + 300ms
```

following the answer to "[Writing custom DirectShow RTSP/RTP Source push filter - timestamping data coming from live sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240151/writing-custom-directshow-rtsp-rtp-source-push-filter-timestamping-data-coming?answertab=votes#tab-top)"

but the results do not change.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would trace reference input which works well with this decoder and then compare media samples you those you feed there in. A missing flag or otherwise a minor thing might be causing the decoder to reject data.

Comment: Roman, Very thanks for your suggestion. Now, I'm analyzing the Media Sample grabbed from the MPEG Splitter Video Output. The graph is: File Source (Async) --> MPEG-I Stream Splitter --> SampleGrabber --> MPEG Video Decoder --> Video Renderer. I'm using the useful tool GraphEditPlus (option "Watch Grabber Sample" on SampleGrabber).